# JPA Link Tables

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am trying to create a link table to link parents/children, both of which are of the same type (person). I'm also trying to create a link table to link players to teams.

In the Team Class, I have:

```
    @OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "PLAYER_TEAM_LINK",
        joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLAYER_ID")})
private List<Player> players;
```

In the Player Class, I have:

```
    @ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name = "PLAYER_TEAM_LINK",
        joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLAYER_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")})
private Team team;
```

For the 2nd scenario, in my Person class, I have:

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "children")
private List<Person> parents;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "PARENT_CHILD_LINK",
        joinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID"))
private List<Person> children;
```

So basically what I am trying to do is generate a link table to link a parent to a child (so the parent id and child id combo would be the primary key), and a parent can have multiple children.

Then, I am trying to create a link table to link teams with players (so the player id and team id combo would be the primary key).

I'm using hibernate as the provider and am using a plugin to do the schema generation, but I can't find the right combination of @ManyToOne, @ManyToMany, etc to generate the link tables with the composite primary keys.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your classes, and what the unit test is doing? You can probably ignore the "PERSON0_", it's just an SQL alias generated by Hibernate...

Comment: I actually switched gears a little bit. Can you help me in a chat session?

Comment: Sorry on my way out... but I'll take a look later if you post code

Answer (score 1):

Your Team-Player association is mapped incorrectly. You're repeating yourself, by declaring how this unique, bidirectional association is mapped twice: once in Team, and once more in Player. One side (the Team side in this case) **must** be the inverse side by using the `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
private List<Player> players;
```

The rest looks correct to me.

I don't see why you're using a join table to map this bidirectional ManyToMany though. Why not simply use a join column in the Player table?

Comment: so I don't need the mappedBy declaration in the @OneToMany on the List<Player>?

Comment: I like your idea of a simple join column. How would I implement that?

Comment: Simply removing the `@JoinTable` annotations and keeping the `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` annotations should give you what you want... (should result in Player having a column with Team ID)

Comment: Actually, since you're not using default column naming Player will need both `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like this page very much: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence it covers lots of different topics concerning the JPA. Especially, you may find the section about the different relation types useful:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables

For each relation type, there are some pretty good examples given.